# HTML being displayed as text

Tags: php, html

#### When I load the following code using php...

`<?php <h1>Some text</h1> ?>`

#### the tags are printed as text -

`<h1>Some text</h1>`

#### Any ideas?

## Found the answer - see my answer.

Comment: You does not used `echo` or `print` for your text. Try this `<h1><?php echo 'Some text'; ?></h1>`

Comment: No they are not, Tags are not printed at all. Nothing is with code provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to output the actual HTML code if you are placing any HTML code within PHP.

You can achieve this using [`echo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).

```php
<?php
    echo("<h1>Some text</h1>");
?>
```

Comment: Figured it out, had content type set. Thanks

Comment: Glad you got it resolved, feel free to post an answer of your own to your question and mark it as the correct one for future reference to anyone else that stumbles upon this question!

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1><?php Some text ?></h1>
```

why dont you try this.

Comment: Figured it out, had content type set. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must print it in order for it to appear the way you want it to

```
<?php echo"<h1>Some text</h1>" ?>
```

like this

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, the content-type was set as json.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo "<h1>Some text</h1>"; ?>
```

```
<?php echo "<h1>Some text</h1>"; ?>
```

if you want to show a variable

```
<?php
$_varTest=2;
echo "<h1>Show variable {$_varTest}</h1>"; ?>
```